# Django makemigrations returns no changes detected

Tags: python, django, django-models

When I want to run `makemigrations`, I get `no changes detected`.
I have this class in my models.

```py
class car (models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I have also added `myapp` in installed apps

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you do migrate after that? you should do "py manage.py migrate" after makemigrations

Answer (score 0):

You can try explicitly specifying the app name when running `makemigrations`, like this:

```
python manage.py makemigrations myapp
```